# Any way to get goodix fingerprint working (Kubuntu 20.10)

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader

This is a frequently asked question, but no one seems to have something that works for my case. I have a *Goodix GXFP3200* fingerprint sensor directly in the touchpad of my labtop (Unowhy Y-13), that isn't detected by `lsusb`. Here is the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:3822 Alcor Micro Corp. USB 2.0 Camera 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If anyone has any workaround / buggy solution, I'll take it. I already tried a lot of things.